# Asp.net (Core) - Navigate to Multiple URLs

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, response.redirect

Using `Custom URL Protocol` I set myself a url with the name **Updater**, which means when I call the following controller;

First example:

```
public IActionResult Launch()
{
    return Redirect("Updater:");
}
```

It runs an .exe file on my machine. However I want to redirect my webpage to the Home page afterwards. Which should look something like this;

Second Example:

```
public IActionResult Launch()
{
    Redirect("Updater:"); // launch my application

    return View("Index"); // and return to homepage
}
```

or in my View something like this;

Third Example:

```
<a href1="@($"ETravelerUpdater:")" href2="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
    <img data-src="holder.js/100px280/thumb?theme=vine">
</a>
```

Is there an easy way to do this ?

**Edit:** The code displayed on second and third example does not work, its only there to give an idea what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why not just include your `Update:` code into your `Launch` action?

Comment: @DavidLee Oh I see what you meant, if I do it as you suggest, the code will run on the server. However currently the code will run on the client machine if the .exe is installed.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your case here, but what you could do is have either on your application or your home page redirect client side to your url.  You can do this with javascript or jquery.  For example you can run this when your Index page loads. `window.location.href = "MyUpdaterLink.com";`

Comment: @DavidLee isint there a way to do this without javascript ?

Comment: What does your `Updater:` action look like?

Comment: @DavidLee my web application is a launcher which allows clients to launch installed applications from my website. Updater, basically checks if there are any updates for the client and then launches the chosen application. It needs to be running on client side. (It is a console application)

Comment: Hard for me to provide a solution without seeing all the pieces.  From what I can see I would suggest using javascript.  I don't think ASP.NET will let you load two pages from a single action.

Comment: @DavidLee can you provide a small example on a cshtml page with a href tag and javascript on the bottom that will allow me to do what I am trying to do ? I can accept this answer if you do so.

Comment: Posted an answer, let me know how it goes for you.

Comment: @DavidLee as soon as try I`ll let you know. Thanks a lot, it looks like its going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the `Updater:` action I have make some assumptions on how it functions.  Either way this should give you an idea on how to handle multiple redirects with javascript from the client.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        window.open('MyUpdaterLink.com', '_blank'); // opens in new tab
        window.location.href = "MyIndexLink.com"; // opens in current window
    }
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">
    <img data-src="holder.js/100px280/thumb?theme=vine">
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional to [David Lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45987117/4279598) I would like to provide an answer that will allow the user to navigate to multiple URLs consequently on the **same tab** using `javascript`;

```
@model LaunchViewModel
<a href="javascript:Launch('ETravelerUpdater:|@Model.EmployeeName|SalesQuotes|@Model.AccessLevel')">
    <img data-src="holder.js/100px280/thumb?theme=sky&text=Sales%20Quotes" alt="Card image cap">
</a>

<script>
    async function Launch(url) {
        window.location.href = url;
        await sleep(1000);
        window.location.href = "./"; 
    }

    function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
</script>
```

After clicking on the anchor tag, the user will navigate to the url parameter and after waiting for a second, the user will navigate to the second url in this case is the home page.